# IDE typing mode, emacs or vim

Tags: eclipse, vim, emacs

First of all, this is not a question on emacs vs vim. I use eclipse IDE for programming and I intend to continue using it. Having read many advantages of emacs and vim, especially the ability to do almost anything without using the mouse, I want to use a similar typing/editing scheme in my eclipse IDE; *I'm aware that there are plugins available* for eclipse to change the editing style to emacs or vim (emacs+, vrapper to name a few..).

Since I plan to continue using eclipse, the various advantages of vim and emacs like small memory foot print, vim/elisp scripting, availability on different platforms, configurablity etc are all lost. I want to import only  the text editing scheme to eclipse and master it while keeping all of eclipse's features.

So, I would like to have an objective comparison of the benefits/disadvantages of only the text editing styles of emacs and vim.

**EDIT**: the reason I cannot move away from eclipse is because my company uses a customized version of eclipse which has specific plugins and dsls to interact with our product(hardware)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I cannot move away from eclipse because my company uses a customized version of eclipse

Please note that **Vim is not an IDE** (a search will bring up various discussions of this topic), therefore this dichotomy does not exist. You can very well use *both* Vim (for text editing) and a real IDE (for debugging, source code browsing, etc.), in parallel. A simple "launch current file in Vim" integration is quickly done, and you've already noted that there are several plugins that bring the basic key bindings (but not the huge customizability) into the IDE.

Also, it strikes me as odd that you have no preconception of Vim vs. Emacs yet. Most people breathe and live their key bindings so much that they desire them in their IDE, too; you just seem to "have heard" about those advantages, but haven't experienced them yet.

My advice: Use your IDE for work (as you have to, anyway), and try out Vim (as well as Emacs) in parallel, maybe for recreational tasks, a little scripting, blogging, whatever. You can then see for yourself whether you'll "get hooked" on one of them, or maybe the IDE will just work out fine for you. Also, time will tell whether a simple integration is sufficient, or whether you want something tight and deep like the *Eclim* project.

Comment: I chose to learn vim, for eclipse I use vrapper :)

Answer (score 1):

I can only tell something about vim, I have used emacs once in a while, but it doesn't seem to be compatible with me. Although I really like scheme which is a lisp dialect.  Vimscript is a horror to program in, but it is possible.

The main feature vim offers is that it adds structure to text beyond the syntax of your language. You can manoeuvre, edit and transform your text with vim's movements. These are at the heart of vim and have to be learned well. This in combination of modes, makes vim a powerful tool for text editing.

On the other hand, for code editing, vim needs some modifications to be useful. You will a considerable amount of configuration. Most people keep their vim configuration in a fire and bullet-proof safe, so they will not lose their painfully built stack of options, plugins and other configurational paraphernalia. That is including me. A vimrc is quite personal. Emacs is easier to configure. I could pick it up much faster.

You have to learn a tremendous amount of knowledge to even be able to use it. Emacs is much easier, you can use it at once. My first encounter with vim was being not be able to leave the damn program, whatever I did. My second encounter, was carefully hitting i and the type some text and quickly hit :wq. But somewhere later I suddenly wanted to tame it.

Vim has macro's, which make a lot of text transforming tasks fun. E.g. this removes al spaces at the end of a line, something I sometimes run to stop the nagging of pylint about spaces:

```
qs:g/ $/s///g<CR>@sq
```

You should read this as: record a macro in register s, replace globally all spaces at the end with nothing, apply macro in register s, stop recording. When hitting:

```
@s
```

This macro will run endlessly, until you are satisfied. I still want to find one, which stops after he hunted the last space. This makes vim fun, it is a little language with one letter commands. You can combine letters together:

```
4f,d$
```

This means find he 4th comma (,) and delete (d) the line from there till the end ($). That makes it quite attractive.

I would personally go for vim, but you have to try the editors out. They have different philosophies and one of those will bite you and the other will seem reasonable.  I don't believe you will find many people, who uses both and mastered both. They are both usable as code editor.

I still have emacs on my wishlist, maybe I will swap.

Comment: If I'm understanding right, there's a simpler alternative to that macro: `:%s/\s\+$//`

Answer (score 0):

This might be of interest:

https://github.com/senny/emacs-eclim

It's a frontend to eclipse, providing Emacs features alongside with Eclipse, not just to mimic Emacs-keys only.
Some screenshots here:

http://www.skybert.net/emacs/java/

Comment: I -1'd this, because the poster says `I plan to continue using eclipse` in his question.

Comment: @admdrew As emacs-eclim does... it's a frontend to eclipse, providing Emacs features alongside with Eclipse, not just to mimic Emacs-keys only.

Comment: Andreas - whoops, sorry, I didn't realize that (I should've actually *read* the github readme). If you make an edit to your post, I can get rid of my downvote.

Comment: @admdrew Okay, done - some explanation might be helpful indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [reading these answers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/986/vim-vs-emacs-and-no-this-is-not-a-flame-war) as they contain a good amount of differences between the two (although a lot of the benefits mentioned don't matter for you). I strongly suggest just trying them out.

A big difference that you will notice is that Vim uses [modes](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_the_vi_Editor/Vim/Modes), which makes it have a high initial learning curve, while Emacs is modeless, and you can use it like a normal text editor (notepad), but with added functionality. And his is where *your* style/preference matters. I personally don't like [holding control down](http://www.unix-manuals.com/refs/emacs/cursor.html) to move around in Emacs, where in Vim, you escape to normal mode and use `hjkl` to move around.